# How to query a PostgreSQL database column whether an item apperas more than once

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to know, how to get a value that is represented more than once in query.

The query:

```
SELECT
    accumulation.partnumber,
    municipality.bez_gem
FROM accumulation, municipality
WHERE ST_Intersects(polygon_accumulation, municipality.geom)
        ORDER BY partnumber
```

bez_gem is the name for a municipality, partnumber an id for an accumulation polygon.
The intersection is between to polygons.

The result:

```
 partnumber |         bez_gem          
------------+--------------------------
          1 | Altdorf b.Nürnberg
          1 | Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.
          2 | Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.
          2 | Altdorf b.Nürnberg
          3 | Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.
          4 | Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.
          4 | Altdorf b.Nürnberg
```

So my question is how to get something like this?

```
 partnumber | more_than_once          
------------+----------------
          1 | t
          2 | t
          3 | f
          4 | t
```

I saw many solutions for MySQL, but not for PostgreSQL.

**EDIT**

table accumulation

```
partnumber integer NOT NULL,
polygon_accumulation geometry(polygon, 31468)
```

table municipality

```
gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('municipality_gid_seq'::regclass),
bez_gem varchar(60),
geom geometry(MultiPolygon, 31468)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select partnumber,
       count(*) > 1 as more_than_once
FROM accumulation, municipality
WHERE ST_Intersects(polygon_accumulation, municipality.geom)
group by partnumber
order by partnumber
```

(I find it a bit confusing that you don't have a proper `JOIN` condition for the two tables, but I assume that this is done through the `ST_Intersect()` function)

Comment: the PostGIS function ST_Intersects() does the job.

Comment: You were first. One could JOIN on the function, btw. Same result. @Benno: you should table-qualify columns in such a case. Since we do not know your table definition this would be the  bare minimum of information, so we can parse it properly.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I edit my question, hoping you mean this with table-qualifying. Thanks for the instruction.

Comment: @Benno: With "table-qualifying" I meant prepending the tablename (or alias) and a dot in front of the column name. Like the `foo.`in  `SELECT foo.col FROM foo JOIN bar USING (foo_id)`. [Details in the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION). But table definitions in your question help as well in this respect. Even better. Preferred form is what you get with `\d partnumber` in psql.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for the advice. I changed my query.